# Django, track session even as user logs in and out

Tags: django, django-sessions

How do I track sessions in Django even after a user has logged in or out? I am using Django authentication.

For example, a user lands on the main page, and maybe follows a few links on my site. Then he logs in. Logs out. Follows some links. I want to track that this is the same user, or at least someone using the same browser session.

I am currently tracking

```
request.user.id
```

which is, of course, specific for a logged in user.

I thought I could use

```
request.session.session_key
```

to track the session, but the session_key changes when the user logs in and again when he logs out.

(What I really want to know is whether the person who lands on my page also logs in / signs up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on the session cookie for this (because indeed, Django automatically rotates it across login / logouts — mainly to prevent session fixation attacks).

Instead, just [create your own cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie), and track users that way.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure that there wasn't some Django built-in way to do it before making my own cookie.